# How to associate the ".exe" extension to be opened with Mono?

Tags: macos, mac, file-association, mono-framework

I want to asssociate the `.exe` file extension to [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) (don't care about wine).

Apparently, when using Finder's GUI, only `.app` files ([application bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Bundle)) can be selected. But the Mono executable (/Libraries/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Current/bin/mono) is no such bundle.

I tried some AppleScript

```
on run this_file
 do shell script "mono this_file &"
end run
```

but Finder's GUI still doesn't allow to associate that with `.exe`'s.

How to associate a specific file extension to a command-line application in Mac OS X?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say about that GUI, but it seems you can find your answer in "How to change file associations on Mac OS X?" at http://superuser.com/questions/29016/how-to-change-file-associations-on-mac-os-x or "Associate a file extension with an app in Snow Leopard" at http://superuser.com/questions/58598/associate-a-file-extension-with-an-app-in-snow-leopard

Comment: When you browse for application apparently only .app files can be selected while mono exetuable (/Libraries/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Current/bin/mono) has no extension. Hence neither GUI way nor RCDefaultApp (in the end uses same select app dialog) doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you use Automator for that AppleScript? In Automator, those can be saved as an application bundle. (But: "Associate a file extension with an app in Snow Leopard" at http://superuser.com/questions/58598/associate-a-file-extension-with-an-app-in-snow-leopard *seems* to have trouble with that as well.)

Comment: It seems my answer worked to associate files with a Python script: see [Set default open-with app to a Python program on a Mac](http://superuser.com/questions/134594/set-default-open-with-app-to-a-python-program-on-a-mac/134599#134599).

Answer (score 4):

Using Automator to save the following as an Application works fine for me, also for new files:

1. Start Automator
2. In "Choose a template for your workflow" choose "Application"
3. Drag the action "Run Shell Script" into the workflow in the pane at the right
4. Change "Pass input" from "to stdin" into "as arguments"
5. Replace `echo "$f"` with `mono "$f" &`. So:

   ```
   for f in "$@"
   do
     mono "$f" &
   done
   ```
6. Save (as an Application)
7. Use Finder to associate any file extension with this new application (like: hit Cmd-I, or right-click » Get Info, select the application and then choose "Change all")

[image]

I have not tested step 5 with `mono`, but with the following, which also uses the command line though:

```
for f in "$@"
do
  open -a /Applications/TextEdit.app/ "$f"
done
```

(I am not an AppleScript expert.)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps above but use this instead:

```
for f in "$@"
do
 mono $f &
done
```