# Set default open-with app to a Python program on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, python, file-association

I use the open source application [UliPad](http://code.google.com/p/ulipad/) to edit restructured text files (rst). It is a Python application that I launch via Terminal like so:

```
python32 UliPad.py
```

I have `python32` as an alias to the 32bit install of Python on my machine. I have several versions installed.

First I would like a way to launch `UliPad` like other OS X apps. Not really sure how to do this.

Secondly, I would like to set all `.rst` files to be opened with `UliPad.py`. Is there a way to do this? I know how to choose the default app in Finder but not sure how to choose UliPad as that app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, according to [How to associate the “.exe” extension to be opened with Mono?](https://superuser.com/questions/67126/how-to-associate-the-exe-extension-to-be-opened-with-mono), you need an `.app` bundle:

> Apparently, when using Finder's GUI, only `.app` files ([application bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application%5FBundle)) can be selected.

If that's true for Python scripts as well, then [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/67126/how-to-associate-the-exe-extension-to-be-opened-with-mono/67180#67180) at that question might help, with for Step 5:

> `5.` Replace `echo "$f"` with `python32 UliPad.py "$f"`

So, in short, create an Automator "application" to run the following Shell script:

```
PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.1/bin/python/
ULIPAD=/Users/vmd/Dropbox/Ulipad/UliPad.py
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  # No parameters passed; just run it without any files:
  $PYTHON $ULIPAD
else
  # Run an instance for each file:
  for f in "$@"
  do
    $PYTHON $ULIPAD "$f"
  done
fi
```

...or maybe you can pass multiple files to `UliPad.py` in one go:

```
PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.1/bin/python/
ULIPAD=/Users/vmd/Dropbox/Ulipad/UliPad.py
$PYTHON $ULIPAD "$@"
```

As for your first question: you should be able to use the same Automator "application" to just start UliPad without opening any file (if indeed you then just need to run it without any parameters, like I assumed above).

Comment: @Arjan, Thanks, I am not sure if Automator uses the .bash-profile with the python alias "python32", I ended up using the actual path to python, and of course the actual path was needed for ulipad.py i.e.
for f in "$@"
do
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.1/bin/python/ /Users/vmd/Dropbox/Ulipad/UliPad.py "$f"
done

Comment: @Vincent, glad it worked. I added an additional `if [ $# -eq 0 ]` in case no files are selected. That should make the "application" start if you just double-click the `.app` bundle from Finder.

Comment: Nice update. One thing I am noticing is that the automator "gear" in the menu bar keeps spinning after ulipad has opened the file. i.e. Automator keeps running so I think it need to me closed. I can probably figure out how but you might what to add it to this great answer.

Comment: @Vincent, you might be able to circumvent that by running Python in the background. That gives Automator control right away. Add an ampersand (`&`) after the two command lines to do that. So: `$PYTHON $ULIPAD &` and `$PYTHON $ULIPAD "$f" &`. Thanks for reporting back!