# How can I make my python application the default for a filetype?

Tags: python

I am making a text editor, and would like it to be the default application to be opened when a file with the extension ".clvr" is double-clicked. I can save it to a folder, but if I click it Windows and Mac both ask me which program to open it in. How can I make my app the default program?

Comment: This is not really a Python question.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I am asking if there is a module or python library that can make my program the default.

Comment: I think some of the big application frameworks (at least Qt) probably have support for this. But are you just looking for something low-level that just wraps up this functionality for various platforms?

Comment: At any rate, this seems like a library-recommendation question. If you looked up how to do it on each platform and then ran into trouble implementing it for one of those platforms, or chose a library and ran into trouble using it, that would be a good question for StackOverflow, but asking for the best library to do this is a good question for some more discussion-oriented forum, maybe the python mailing list.

Comment: For Mac, I think you just want to declaratively specify the file type in your Info.plist, then `LaunchServices` should default to your app. (During development testing, every time you change anything, you'll want to run `lsregister` inside the `LaunchServices.framework` to force it to reload your bundle; I don't remember the details, but it has a `--help`.) Unless you're worried that some other app happens to want to claim the same extension for a different filetype, but in that case you're supposed to leave it up to the user, not force yourself.

Comment: If that all sounds like gobbledegook, you probably need to start at [the UTI overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) and then read the details on defining UTIs and then about how LaunchServices document claims work.

Comment: For Mac: http://superuser.com/questions/134594/set-default-open-with-app-to-a-python-program-on-a-mac?rq=1 and Windows: http://superuser.com/questions/476390/changing-file-extension-associations

Comment: @Mokubai: From the question it seems he wants to associate the program he's coding with a particular file type *from within the program itself*. I have no idea why this was migrated here because it's clearly an SO question.